# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at application.DashboardController.initialize(DashboardController.java:255)

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I am using javafx and trying to understand what caused this error. 
I know know what NullPointerException is but what does

> at
>   application.DashboardController.initialize(DashboardController.java:255)

mean? Is my error on this line as I don't know how the code on this line could be causing problems.

This is line 255.

> circle1.setOnMouseEntered(e -> getInfo(Symptom1.getText(), circle1,
>                   date1, data));

my controller class

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        Calendar date1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 05, 01);
        Calendar date2 = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 02, 05);
        Calendar date3 = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 06, 07);
        Calendar date4 = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 07, 14);
        Calendar date5 = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 07, 23);

        p1 = new Patient(400667279,"Paul", "King", 1952, 11, "School Road, Lisburn", "BT27 4BH", "Male");

        //Date of symptom - Label
        data.setText(null);
        data2.setText(null);
        data3.setText(null);
        data4.setText(null);
        data5.setText(null);

        //name of symptom - Label
        Symptom1.setText("change in bowel habit");
        Symptom2.setText("blood in the stools");
        Symptom3.setText("high temperature");
        Symptom4.setText("Constipation");
        Symptom5.setText("persistent cough");

        double day1 = getDays(Symptom1.getText(), date1);
        double day2 = getDays(Symptom2.getText(), date2);
        double day3 = getDays(Symptom3.getText(), date3);
        double day4 = getDays(Symptom4.getText(), date4);
        double day5 = getDays(Symptom5.getText(), date5);

        double maxWidth = 500.0;
        Boolean flag = false;
        double biggest = 0;
        double all = day1 + day2 + day3 + day4 + day5;

        for (double i = all; flag == false; i--) {
            if ((i == day1) || (i == day2) || (i == day3) || (i == day4)
                    || (i == day5)) {
                flag = true;
                biggest = i;
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(biggest);
        double Onepercent = maxWidth / biggest;

        shape1.setWidth(Onepercent * day1);
        shape2.setWidth(Onepercent * day2);
        shape3.setWidth(Onepercent * day3);
        shape4.setWidth(Onepercent * day4);
        shape5.setWidth(Onepercent * day5);

        circle1.setOnMouseEntered(e -> getInfo(Symptom1.getText(), circle1,
                date1, data));
        circle2.setOnMouseEntered(e -> getInfo(Symptom2.getText(), circle2,
                date2, data2));
        circle3.setOnMouseEntered(e -> getInfo(Symptom3.getText(), circle3,
                date3, data3));
        circle4.setOnMouseEntered(e -> getInfo(Symptom4.getText(), circle4,
                date4, data4));
        circle5.setOnMouseEntered(e -> getInfo(Symptom5.getText(), circle5,
                date5, data5));

        circle1.setOnMouseExited(e -> Exit(circle1, data));
        circle2.setOnMouseExited(e -> Exit(circle2, data2));
        circle3.setOnMouseExited(e -> Exit(circle3, data3));
        circle4.setOnMouseExited(e -> Exit(circle4, data4));
        circle5.setOnMouseExited(e -> Exit(circle5, data5));

        DateTableView.setItems(SetDates());
    }
```

my fxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="438.0" prefWidth="826.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.DashboardController">
   <top>
      <Label text="Dashboard" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
         <font>
            <Font size="33.0" />
         </font>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </Label>
   </top>
   <bottom>
  <Pane prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="635.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
   <center>
     <VBox id="Column" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="309.0"     prefWidth="603.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <HBox id="Row1" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" depthTest="ENABLE" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="399.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="92.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label fx:id="Symptom1" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="86.0" text="symptom 1">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets right="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="data" text="Label" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle fx:id="circle1" fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape1" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.66" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape12" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.34" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape13" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </VBox>
           </children>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets />
           </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
        <HBox id="Row2" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="587.0">
           <children>
              <VBox prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="88.0">
                 <children>
                    <Label id="symptom2" fx:id="Symptom2" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="symptom 2">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets right="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="data2" text="Label" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape2" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.66" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape22" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.34" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape23" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </VBox>
           </children>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets />
           </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
        <HBox id="Row3" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="580.0">
           <children>
              <VBox prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="123.0">
                 <children>
                    <Label fx:id="Symptom3" text="symptom 3">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets right="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="data3" text="Label" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape3" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.66" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape32" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.34" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape33" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </VBox>
           </children>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets />
           </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
        <HBox id="Row4" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="520.0">
           <children>
              <VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="111.0">
                 <children>
                    <Label fx:id="Symptom4" text="symptom 4">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets right="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="data4" text="Label" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape4" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.66" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape42" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.34" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape43" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </VBox>
           </children>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets />
           </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
        <HBox id="Row5" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="540.0">
           <children>
              <VBox prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="116.0">
                 <children>
                    <Label fx:id="Symptom5" text="symptom5">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets right="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="data5" text="Label" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                          <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                          <Rectangle fx:id="shape5" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.66" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                       <children>
                              <Circle  fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                              <Rectangle fx:id="shape52" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" opacity="0.34" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                           <children>
                              <Circle fill="#5a5a5b" radius="4.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                              <Rectangle fx:id="shape53" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#5a5a5b" height="3.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="523.0" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="584.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="DateTableView" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="616.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <left>
      <StackPane prefHeight="329.0" prefWidth="33.0"             BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <right>
      <VBox prefHeight="318.0" prefWidth="159.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <padding>
            <Insets top="40.0" />
         </padding>
         <children>
            <PieChart  prefHeight="156.0" prefWidth="95.0" />
            <PieChart  />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/User/workspace2/AssistMedicalCare/bin/fmxl/DashBoard.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.MenuController.ShowDashBoard(MenuController.java:108)
    at application.MenuController.HandleDashBoardView(MenuController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$195/1312089785.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.DashboardController.initialize(DashboardController.java:257)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace

Comment: Yes, the piece you quoted is the line number. Which line is line 255?

Comment: Line 255, or is it line 257? Your question is inconsistent between edits...

Comment: it is now 257 but it is the same code.

Comment: Then `circle1` is `null`. Can you show how you have declared it (I assume it is `@FXML`-injected?). It seems more likely the exception is coming from two lines down, as you have no `fx:id="circle2"` anywhere in your FXML code...

Comment: yeah that's what it was. I must have accidentally deleted them. Thanks